# Android Persistent Cookie Store with HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: android, cookiestore, android-cookiemanager

I searched a lot now for the persistence of Cookies but cant find a good solution.

I use HTTPUrlConnection to authenticate against a server and I get Cookies back. I retrieve them in CookieManager and can load them into a new connection. Now I want to persistent that Cookies, perhaps the whole Cookiemanager Object. I found a solution, that you can persist the Cookies with specifying a CookieStore by creating the CookieManager.

I found only old solutions (2-3 years) that say you have to build your own persistent CookieStore, since a persistent CookieStore is not implemented in the SDK? Is this up to date? Is there already a persistent CookieStore implemented in the SDK or does I have to persist the Cookies by myself with SharedPreferences? Or does anybody has a better solution to persist Cookies nowadays?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be answered in some other palces, I didn't try it but you can get a detailed explain in this link:

http://blog.winfieldpeterson.com/2013/01/17/cookies-in-hybrid-android-apps/

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //Setup Cookie Manager and Persistence to disk
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
  }
}

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
  public void onResume() {
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync();
  }

   public void onPause() {
     CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
   }
}
```

API21 deprecates CookieSyncManager, now to ensure that cookies are written to disk use:

```
CookieManager.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks, but CookieSyncManager was deprecated in API21.

Comment: I add a API21 wokarround to the article, I not tested it. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that you can write to persistant storage with CookieManager.flush() but CookieManager doesnt has a method to retrieve from persistant storeage? I think perhaps you have to write a Cookie Storage by yourself and CookieManager.flush() will write it to the CookieStore when you defined a CookieStore in the initialisation of CookieManager and calls up a method of your custom CookieStore. I will proof that later. Best regards.